# How to modify the theme used by windows within a program?

Tags: windows-10, themes

I'm using Windows 10. I want to create a dark theme for the program that I'm using. I can change the color of everything except for the window title bars (light blue), which looks similar to the windows 7 basic theme. These are modified by the high contrast windows built-in theme, but I don't like it, and just want to keep the default windows 10 theme and modify the theme that the program is using.

Any suggestions?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD83I.png)

Comment: Why not just enable the dark theme in Settings?

Comment: @Biswapriyo That screenshot was made with dark mode enabled

Comment: If the application does not support Windows 10 themes there isn't a great deal you can do about it.  I am pretty sure the Windows 10 Dark Mode is only supported by UWP applications anyways.